Maxflow-mincut implies Menger (vertices)
I was studying graph theory when a question came to my mind.
I am trying to understand a proof of the Menger's theorem (vertex version) using the maxflow-mincut (capacity on vertices). I think I miss something about flows. Note that in the following capacities are defined on vertices.
The proof goes roughly like this. Given two non-adjacent vertices u and v (in a non-oriented graph), consider the network having the same vertices of the graph, having u and v as respectively source and target, with two oriented edges for every edge of the original graph, and having as capacity 1 for every vertex (different from u and v). The separating sets of the network (i.e. the sets of vertices such that for every path from u to v crosses a vertex in the set) coincide with the separating set of the graph (analogously defined), and given the capacity defined above, the capacity of a separating set equals its cardinality. Now, for the maxflow-mincut theorem, there exists an integer-value flow and whose value equals the minimum cardinality k of the separating set.
The problem now is: how to extract k disjoint paths from u to v from that flow? On my notes, they say that the flow, having value k, must be non-zero on at least k disjoint directed paths from s to t, since if two of those paths had a vertex in common, the entering flow would be at least 2 overcoming the capacity.
Just some of my perplexities:

the flow is a maps from edges; what does it mean for a flow to be non-zero on a path?
I can see why a vertex cannot have more than two entering arcs valued 1 by the flow (depending of the capacity defined); but I cannot see how two paths crossing in a vertex would cause it to have flow >=2: choosing the first arc of the paths in common, I would know it has two different entering arcs, but how come the latter have flow 1?
the k paths mentioned are some specific paths (characterisable in terms of the flow) or it is just k arbitrary paths? and, in this case, why the flow has non-zero value on them (whatever it means, see point (1))? From the flow having value k the best I can do is to deduce that the source has at least k 1-valued exiting arcs.

Disclaimer Before asking this question, I've read (at least some) of the answers on the topic and none of them seems to suffice.

Please forgive my notation. We assume graphs are directed, otherwise put an edge in both directions. Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph and $f:E\to\mathbb Z_+$ be an $s$-$t$ flow with value $k$ (where $s$,$t$ are non-adjacent). By definition of capacities, for any vertex $v\in V':=V-s-t$,
$$(*)\quad\quad\quad f(\delta^-(v))\leq 1\quad\text{ and }\quad f(\delta^+(v))\leq 1\quad\text{ and }\quad  f(\delta^+(v))=f(\delta^-(v)).$$
In particular this means that for any edge $e=uv$, $f(e)\leq f(\delta^+(u))\leq 1$, so $f$ takes only values from $\{0,1\}$ (this also holds if $e=su$ or $e=ut$). To show that this flow "represents" $k$ internally disjoint paths, we can show that $F:=\{e\in E\mid f(e)=1\}=\{\textit{edges where flow is nonzero}\}$ is literally the edge set of some specific collection $\mathcal P$ of $k$ internally disjoint $s$-$t$ paths.
By $(*)$, we cannot have two edges $e_1,e_2\in F$ both entering (or both leaving) the same vertex $v\in V'$. Also, if there is an edge entering $v$, there must be another edge leaving $v$. Finally, we know that there are $k$ edges in $F$ entering $t$, and $k$ edges leaving $s$. This should satisfy your intuition. However, using induction you can use this structure to formally decompose/extract $F$ into a collection $\mathcal P$ of $k$ paths.
Edit: $F$ may contain cycles as well. Thus we really want to decompose $F$ into $k$ paths and some unknown number of directed cycles.

Thank you for your clear answer. It addresses (1) directly and (2) implicitly. (3) still leaves me perplexed: I cannot figure it out how the non-zero arcs build up paths from s to t. It's clear that arcs do not enter or leave the same vertex in V' (which corresponds to the internally-disjointness of those putative paths), but how do I characterise them? What do I use induction on?

Consider applying induction on $k$ (base case $F=\emptyset$, $\mathcal P=\emptyset$). For the inductive case, first try to show that $F$ contains at least one $s$-$t$ path $P$. Then observe that $F-P$ satisfies all the conditions for the inductive hypothesis, so $F-P$ can be decomposed into $k-1$ disjoint paths. Glossing over some details, that’s the idea.

I'd like to prove, in particular, that s has k non-zero leaving arcs and no non-zero entering arc, and that the dual is valid for t. How could one address that?

@AmandaWealth Thanks for pointing this out. This is not necessarily true. Your flow may contain some extraneous directed cycles. All that you know is that there are $k$ more non-zero arcs leaving $s$ than entering $s$ (by definition of flow value). At this point, you could either (1) delete any cycles (you don’t need them) and proceed with a decomposition, or (2) inductively extract $k$ paths and don't worry about cycles. I believe either strategy works.

Are you familiar with the situation involving arcs instead of vertices? How can one prove in that case that the set of non-zero arcs forms k arcs-disjoint simple paths?

The same induction approach should work. i.e. prove that $F$ contains an $s$-$t$ path $P$. Then show $F'=F-E(P)$ satisfies the inductive hypothesis so $F'$ contains $k-1$ arc-disjoint $s$-$t$ paths.
